# How to Replicate SQLite Database from Android Device to MySQL on Server (1 way)

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite

I am trying to build an Android App that Stores Images and Data in a SQLite Database on an Android device. I want to replicate the SQLite DB to MySQL on my website. It's going to be a 1 way sync that SQLite copies data to MYSQL.

How can i replicate the DB, to maintain data conflict, i would use timestamps or semaphores.
Any help would really be appreciated!